# How to put that code in a reusable function?

Tags: php

I have that code that works fine but looks messy especially that i will need to repeat that foreach loop 6 times then will merge the output array of each loop in a single multidimensional array, the code below showing doing that with the loop written 2 times.

```
$prodo = array();
$uk_array = array();
$de_array = array();
// set counter you want to iterate over.
$j =0;
$step = 5; // set the step value (in your case it will 50.) 
$n = count($asins_array)/$step;

$associate_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$access_key = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$secret_key = "xxxxxxxxxx";

for($i = 0 ;$i<$n;$i++)
{

    $asin = implode(',',array_slice($asins_array,$j,$step));
    $j = $j+$step; // increment counter by to step position. 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($asin); // this is the collection you want. save it or use directly   
echo "</pre>";


//////////////////// How to put that code from this point to the point idicated below in a function wth arguments///// 


    $amazon = new AmazonAPI($associate_id , $access_key, $secret_key , "amazon.co.uk");
    $item = $amazon->item_lookup($asin);

    $url = $amazon->build_url();
    echo $url;



    foreach($amazon->xml->Items->Item as $item)
    {
        $amz_asin =   (string)$item->ASIN;
        $amz_price = number_format($item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->Amount/100, 2);
        $amz_title =   (string)$item->ItemAttributes->Title;
        //$amz_desc =   (string)$item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview->Content;
        $amz_feature =   (string)$item->ItemAttributes->Feature;

        $product_array =  array ("UK" => array ("Title" => $amz_title , "Price" => $amz_price));

        $uk_array [$amz_asin] = $product_array;

    }

/////////////////

    $amazon = new AmazonAPI($associate_id , $access_key, $secret_key , "amazon.de");
    $item = $amazon->item_lookup($asin);

    $url = $amazon->build_url();
    echo $url;


    foreach($amazon->xml->Items->Item as $item)
    {
        $amz_asin =   (string)$item->ASIN;
        $amz_price = number_format($item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->Amount/100, 2);
        $amz_title =   (string)$item->ItemAttributes->Title;
        //$amz_desc =   (string)$item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview->Content;
        $amz_feature =   (string)$item->ItemAttributes->Feature;

        $product_array =  array ("DE" => array ("Title" => $amz_title , "Price" => $amz_price));

        $de_array [$amz_asin] = $product_array;

        ///////////////


    }


}


$prodo = array_merge_recursive($de_array , $uk_array );

print_r ($prodo);
```

I tried to do it like this but it didnt work,When i add the following line only

```
$uk_array [$amz_asin] = amz_xml_array('amazon.co.uk','UK',$asin);
```

and print that variable i get the uk array properly

and when i replace the above uk line with the following line i get the de array properly
$de_array [$amz_asin] = amz_xml_array('amazon.de','DE',$asin);

but when i add both lines and try merge them using array_merge_recursive outside the loop i get part of the array array merged nicely and part of it looks messy, i tried to test it by leaving both uk and de variables and just print one of them without merging i get the UK array having some elements from the de array!

```
$product_details = array();
function amz_xml_array ($amazon_domain,$arr_country_code,$asin) {
    global $product_details;

    $associate_id = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    $access_key = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    $secret_key = "xxxxxxxxxx";

    $amazon = new AmazonAPI($associate_id , $access_key, $secret_key , $amazon_domain);
    $item = $amazon->item_lookup($asin);

    $url = $amazon->build_url();
    echo $url;

    foreach($amazon->xml->Items->Item as $item)
    {
        $amz_asin =   (string)$item->ASIN;
        $amz_price = number_format($item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->Amount/100, 2);
        $amz_title =   (string)$item->ItemAttributes->Title;
        $product_array =  array ($arr_country_code => array ("Title" => $amz_title , "Price" => $amz_price)); //Build array from Amazon API XML
        $product_details [$amz_asin] = $product_array;      //get the array outside the loop
    }

    return $product_details;
}




$uk_array = array();
$de_array = array();

// set counter you want to iterate over.
$j =0;
$step = 5; // set the step value (in your case it will 50.) 
$n = count($asins_array)/$step;

for($i = 0 ;$i<$n;$i++) {
    $asin = implode(',',array_slice($asins_array,$j,$step));
    $j = $j+$step; // increment counter by to step position. 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($asin); // this is the collection you want. save it or use directly   
echo "</pre>";

$uk_array [$amz_asin] = amz_xml_array('amazon.co.uk','UK',$asin);
$de_array [$amz_asin] = amz_xml_array('amazon.de','DE',$asin);

}

//$prodo = array_merge_recursive($de_array , $uk_array );
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($uk_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

So im wondering if there is something im doing wrong?!

Comment: You are replacing all the values with every loop without using them. So in the end there is only one value, because the others are being replaced by the next value.

Comment: Think you might need to change the return from the function to `return $product_details;` (without the array index)

Comment: @YongQuan Thankf for reply, i updated the question, I think what you mentioned maybe the problem but im still dont know how to solve it

Comment: @NigelRen thanks, returning the variable only solved part of the issue, I updated the question to show what i achieved so far

Comment: Try using namespace!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the details mixed up as you are not re-initialising the `$product_details` array.  You should try and avoid using `global` in general and this is one example of why.

Instead create a new array in each loop...

```
function amz_xml_array ($amazon_domain,$arr_country_code,$asin) {
    $product_details = array();

}
```